# Sorting the contacts list alphabetically and show in tableview groups?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, alphabetical

I have array of contacts(NSObject)

```
@interface Contact : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *number;

@end
```

`contacts = @[contact1, contact2, contact3, contact3, contact4, contact5];`

i want to show them alphabetically under sections in UITableview
dynamically.

any suggestions would be more appreciated?

Comment: Use [Sorting](https://www.ios-blog.com/tutorials/objective-c/how-to-sort-nsarray-with-custom-objects/) first and then Use [Grouping](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39690/splitting-an-nsarray-into-an-nsdictionary-of-array-more-elegantly)

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I know thats why i shared obj-c link. Check. If you found wrong then let me knoe.

Comment: not related : do not use retain, use strong instead

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Under ARC, `retain` is a synonym to `strong`.

Comment: @rmaddy yes correct but now everyone is using strong, I have seen very less dev. using retain now

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I agree you should use `strong`, but `retain` will work and will be treated the same as `strong`.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes correct :)

Comment: @zack Your question is not very clear to me. Where are you facing the issue in sorting or in task of showing in tableview ?

Comment: i want to sort in alphabetical order like iphone contacts in sections.